# Avoid "ifChanged" event handler when setting checkbox via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

for iCheck plugin, is there a way to avoid "ifChanged" event handler to fire up when setting the checkbox from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a variable *ignoreChange* and when subscribing to the event handler, checking whether that variable is *true* and if it is, then set it to *false* and stop the function. If it is not *true*, then you can execute your normal code.

JS code:

```
var ignoreChange = false;

$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){

    if (ignoreChange) {
        ignoreChange = false;
        return;
    }

    // do stuff
});

// When changing the checkbox
ignoreChange = true;
```

Basically, whenever you set the variable *ignoreChange* to true, the next event call is ignored. This is quite a hacky workaround, however necessary, as I did not find a way to solve your problem trough the iCheck library.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is the only way to do it. I tried to avoid globals as much as possible but looks like it's unavoidable in JS environment. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but I found a better method is to check the `event.target.checked` property and only run your code if it returns true. iCheck fires `ifChanged` *twice* - first for the un-checked option, then secondly for the checked option. So if you only run your code if `event.target.checked === true`, you will get the result you are after.